# grep base on specific date

Tags: grep, find

I have a file somewhere on my linux hard drive which I know was created in November, 2007. I have tried find and grep *.* Nov ?? 2007 in MANY combinations with no success. What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure unless you provide info on all you tried. `find`  can retrieve files created between specified dates, so with only find, you can list all files of november 2007.

Comment: You don't specify what syntax you used with find. Look at the accepted answer for this question (https://serverfault.com/questions/122824/linux-using-find-to-locate-files-older-than-date) , then look at the additional comments which use the '!' to negate the -newer switch on find.

Answer (score 5):

You're possibly confusing *shell globs* (where `?` matches any single character) with grep *regular expressions* (where `?` is either literal, or a quantifier - while `.` matches any single character).

Regardless, `grep` isn't the right tool for this - you can specify a file modification date range to GNU `find` using `-newermt`:

```
find path/to/drive/ -type f -newermt '2007-10-31' ! -newermt '2007-12-01'
```

Comment: @Rogo AFAIK it's normal for things like `~/.dbus` and `~/.gvfs` to only be accessible to their owner - I suspect you would have seen those permission errors eventually **without** excluding some directories, you're likely just encountering them sooner since `find` is now searching fewer places